# Finding new mean and standard deviation given initial values for both

Tags: random-variables, standard-deviation, variance, means, expected-value

I'd appreciate any assistance on this:

On average, a salesperson makes a sale to 60% of their contacts in a given day with a standard deviation of 2.2%. Assume the salesperson makes 20 contacts per day and makes $35 on each sale. Let X be a random variable denoting the percentage of sales in a given day. Find the mean and standard deviation of the salesperson's total daily commission.